# Xamarin horizontal view with buttons

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

any ideas how to prepare such an element as at the picture ?
I need 5 buttons to be there so i could swipe through them but only 3 one them are visible all the time. I need this to work on android and ios in xamarin forms.


[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Add ScrollView and set it's orientation to horizontal

```
ScrollView = new ScrollView
{
    Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal
};

//ScrollView.Scrolled += ScrollView_Scrolled;

ItemsStackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    Padding = new Thickness(0),
    Spacing = 0,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};

ScrollView.Content = ItemsStackLayout;
```

you can set the width of the elements inside 1/3 of the view width

FYI I use the same in my app
[image: I use the same in my App]

Comment: when im trying to swipe on it , it catches the event from carousel which holds four different contentviews. any thoughts?

Comment: What event ? I didn't get you question

Comment: I mean this ContentView control has Carousel above it, and when i swipe on the list, carousel changes layouts instead of our horizontal scrollview